# When importing, QtQuick.Controls 1.4 does not apply Material Style

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In the QML application I need a Calendar. It is located in QtQuick.Controls 1.4. But as soon as I import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 Material Style ceases to work.
How do I use Calendar, but not lose Material Style?

```
#include <QQuickStyle>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0
//import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtQuickControls 1.x and 2.x can have Components with the same name which causes them to overlap (depending on what was imported first). When importing QQuick 1.x stuff, I suggest defining a custom name in the import statement. Here is a working example for calendar:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QtQuickControls1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    QtQuickControls1.Calendar { 
        id: calendar
    }
}
```